# Cassandra Datastax driver not giving error when update fails

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE codingjedi.users (
    bucket int,
    email text,
    authprovider text,
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    confirmed boolean,
    hasher text,
    id uuid,
    password text,
    salt text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((bucket, email), authprovider, firstname, lastname)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (authprovider ASC, firstname ASC, lastname ASC)
```

I tried to update a row of the table but I didn't fully qualify the row. I specified only `partition key` and partially specified the `clustering columns`

```
def updateValues(tableName:String, model:User, id:UserKeys):Update.Where = {
    QueryBuilder.update(tableName).`with`(QueryBuilder.set("confirmed",model.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.confirmed))/*(QueryBuilder.set("authprovider",model.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.loginInfo.providerID)) //TODOM - remove hardcoding for bucket and also add bucket in User model*/
      .and(QueryBuilder.set("id",model.id))
      .and(QueryBuilder.set("password",model.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.passwordInfo.get.password))
      .and(QueryBuilder.set("hasher",model.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.passwordInfo.get.hasher))
      .and(QueryBuilder.set("salt",""/*model.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.passwordInfo.get.salt.get*/)) //salt is empty for BCryptSha256PasswordHasher. The 'hash' method of BCryptSha256PasswordHasher does not return the salt separately because it is embedded in the hashed password.
      .where(QueryBuilder.eq("bucket", id.bucket)) //TODOM - pick column names from config/env file
      .and(QueryBuilder.eq("email", id.email))
      .and(QueryBuilder.eq("authprovider", model.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.loginInfo.providerID))//TODOM - this should come from id
      .and(QueryBuilder.eq("firstname",model.profile.externalProfileDetails.firstName))
      /*.and(QueryBuilder.eq("lastname",model.profile.externalProfileDetails.lastName))*//*REMOVED a clustering column value*/

  }
```

The above query fails and the row isn't updated but I also don't see any error messages in the console.

But if I try the same in `cqlsh`, I see error `InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Some clustering keys are missing: lastname"`.

Why `Datastax` isn't reporting error and how could I make it show errors?

Comment: How this query is executed? Via execute or executeAsync?

Comment: I used `execute`

Comment: Check that you don't have exception handler somewhere... Bad query should throw an exception https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.5/com/datastax/driver/core/Session.html#execute-java.lang.String-

Comment: I am certain I don’t have an exception handler as I have seen exceptions for other scenarios

Comment: I can  think only that it's executed in the separate thread, and exception is handled somewhere else... Try to enable logging for driver: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/logging/